# Querying Relationship Fields in Lumen/Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

So i got a bit of a problem here with Laravel relationships.

I have a **model** for lead conversions and it has a **hasOne** relationship with a **details** model, the details model contains a **hashkey** field that i need to use.

```
public function details()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CampaignDetails', 'n_idcampaign', 'n_idcampaign')->select(['n_idcampaign', 'hashkey']);
}
```

So far so good, i really only need the **hashkey** but i need to return the idcampaign as well as a foreign key or else it won't work for some reason...

When i query the model i do the following.

```
return $this->model->with('details')->where('n_idcampaign', 1884)->first();
```

So far, so good, it returns the whole thing, it's a pain to access it like `first()->details->hashkey` but at least it works...

The bigger problem appears when i need to do where queries based on the Hashkey...

```
return $this->model->with('details')->where('idData', $id)->where('hashkey', $haskkey)->first();
```

This doesn't work, how can i make it so that i can query the main model  based on a **field from a relationship** (in this case **hashkey**)

Comment: Maybe try wherePivot() instead of where? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @wouthoekstra `wherePivot` is used for `belongsToMany` relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If your need to constrain your query based on a relationship you can use the `whereHas()` method.

```
return $this->model->with('details')
    ->where('idData', $id)
    ->whereHas('details', function ($query) use ($haskkey) {
        return $query->where('hashkey', $haskkey);
    })
    ->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Hope this helps!